# d3 timeline axis - line chart bug with animation - x.bandwidth error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a line chart with the ability to toggle on and off the lines -but I am getting an x.bandwidth error possibly because my axis is based on scaletime --

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/235/

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width]);
```

what would be the equivalent of x.bandwidth?

```
  x.domain(newKeys).rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]);
```

Comment: I've bypassed the errors using width and readjusted the x1 to x - but still no animation - http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/242/

Comment: First of all, the x domain wouldn't be "newKeys" as x is a time scale (i.e. won't be dependent on the city name as it is NOT an ordinal scale). In this case, only the y domain will change. Once that's done, try adding the transitions.

Comment: I'm not sure @Shashank - sure so the timescale woulnd't change - but some lines would start further in the past ? So if you don't change the timescale your remaining line may look small?

Comment: How do I fix this @Shashank to filter the data for the line chart?

Comment: I'll add a fiddle asap!

Comment: var t0 = svg.transition().duration(250);
     var t1 = t0.transition();
     t1.selectAll(".yaxis").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));

Comment: g.select(".yaxis")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));

Comment: That would correctly update and transition the y-axis. But, the way the paths are rerendered in the update function seem to be not right.

Comment: In what way? Demo of a better approach? @Shashank

Comment: here is the jsfiddle I got for the grouped bar chart - http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/259/

Comment: I've added a parseDate and rejigged the line chart -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/260/ - but need to fix the transitions - need help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833778/d3js-group-and-line-chart-animation-legend-toggling/46836030#46836030)

If everything is as per your requirement, please mark the answer as right and we could close this issue.

Comment: Cheers @Shashank - there is a bounty for cleaning this up to make the bar and line chart sister-like -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700389/d3-js-curved-line-charts-with-toggle-legends