# d3js group and line chart animation - legend toggling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a line chart equilvant of this group chart - with legend toggling. I am not sure I've got the animation correct - and want to essentially make the charts sisters in terms of structure.

//group chart
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/259/

//line chart
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/262/

```
g.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)";
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return keys.map(function(key) {
      return { key: key, value: d[key]};
    });
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.key);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {            
    return z(d.key);
  });
```

-- so the line one looks like this - but I think I am missing enter() parts

```
// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { 
      return x(parseTime(d.date));
     })
    .y(function(d) { 
      return y(d.temperature); 
    });

g.selectAll(".city")
  .data(cities)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "city")
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d){
    return valueline(d.values);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return z(d.id);
  });
```

also when it comes to toggling the legends how do I fix the line chart to animate the lines - and fix the domains - as one is now a timescale. Also in reference to both charts - should I place the "make bars" "make lines" code seen above - into an actual function - that gets reused during the update function method - for each chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/0ht35rpb/264/) that has the animations as per your requirement.

Relevant code:

```
y.domain([
  d3.min(cities, function(c) {
  if(filtered.indexOf(c.id) === -1) {
    return d3.min(c.values, function(d) {
      return d.temperature;
    });
    }
  }),
  d3.max(cities, function(c) {
  if(filtered.indexOf(c.id) === -1) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
      return d.temperature;
    });
    }
  })
]);

  g.select(".axis.axis--y").transition().duration(500)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    g.selectAll('.city path').transition().duration(500).attr('d', function(d) { 
    if(filtered.indexOf(d.id) > -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return valueline(d.values);
    }
  });
```

Your code was missing a lot of things:

1. X axis is a time scale, and in your case, you don't need to update the x-axis in the update function as your toggling based on the city names and not the dates.
2. Event if you had a changing X-axis, you wouldn't change the domain that way. Time scale looks for dates and it seems like you were setting that to the city names. ("newKeys")
3. Setting the y-domain is to be based on the "cities" array as you are using that to render the chart. But in the update function, you seem to be using "data" array to set the y domain and hence the y-axis issue.
4. Added transition to the y-axis too.
5. `var paths = svg.selectAll(".line").selectAll("path")` is not what you want as you have the class "line" for the path itself. A relevant version would be: `svg.selectAll("path.line")`
6. Anyway, the filtering of the paths wouldn't work as the selection was wrong and as far as the filtering is concerned, the paths are calling the "line" function whereas the line function in your code is defined as "valueline"
7. Filtering of the paths in a similar fashion as yours would be correct in this way:

> ```
>   g.selectAll('.city path').transition().duration(500)
>     .attr('d', function(d) { 
>       if(filtered.indexOf(d.id) > -1) {
>           return null;
>         } else {
>           return valueline(d.values);
>       }
>       });
> ```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Cheers @Shashank - there is a bounty for cleaning this up to make the bar and line chart sister-like -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700389/d3-js-curved-line-charts-with-toggle-legends